# No puedo hacer el modelo de mi objeto mongodb nodejs

Tags: javascript, java, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

tengo este modelo en json original desde java, y estoy intentando obtener cierta información en mi página web. Pero no me funciona el traspaso o más bien el modelo, pues me retorna null o un array vacío.

Si es necesario puedo otorgar más información respecto al error, pero de momento esto es lo que tengo.

He intentado bastante, pero aun no logro solucionar ni encontrar el error para ver por donde partir, pues no sé qué es lo que está mal en el código.

Objeto original Java:

```
    private final String name;
    private final UUID uuid;
    private final HashMap < String, Boolean > options = new HashMap <>( );
    private final HashMap < String, String > properties = new HashMap <>( );
    private final HashMap < UUID, PunishType > punishments = new HashMap <>( );
    private final HashMap < String, Long > countDowns = new HashMap <>( );
    private final ArrayList < Reward > rewards = new ArrayList <>( );
    private final ArrayList < UUID > friends = new ArrayList <>( );
    private final Date dateCreate;
    private String gameModeId;
    private LyCoins lyCoins;
    private Level level;
    private ClanRel clan;
    private LastLocation lastLocation;
    private String address;
    private LobbyVanishType lobbyVanishType;
    private Rank rank;
```

Objeto en JSON:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61e121350b91bXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "name": "BarraR3port",
    "uuid": "19b34bb5-b10e-3107-8615-XXXXXXXXXX",
    "options": {
        "spawn_tp": true,
        "announcements_normal": true,
        "join_message": true,
        "private_msg": true,
        "announcements_streams": true
    },
    "properties": {
        "lobby": "lobbyantilag",
        "lobby_vanish": "all",
        "join_message": "&aaaHolaaaaaaaaa "
    },
    "punishments": {},
    "countDowns": {},
    "rewards": [],
    "friends": [],
    "dateCreate": "Jan 14, 2022 7:07:33 AM",
    "gameModeId": "core",
    "lyCoins": {
        "coins": 124265
    },
    "level": {
        "uuid": "19b34bb5-b10e-3107-8615-XXXXXXX",
        "ownerType": "PLAYER",
        "level": 2,
        "levelName": "§8[2✩]",
        "currentXp": 7445
    },
    "clan": {
        "clanId": "0078108a-356b-451b-bdbf-XXXXXXXXXX",
        "rank": "OWNER"
    },
    "lastLocation": {
        "Server": "bw2futu1",
        "World": "bw_temp_y22m01d14g0",
        "X": -9.016146790813986,
        "Y": 159,
        "Z": -11.061482189357449,
        "Yaw": 40.771393,
        "Pitch": 13.989314
    },
    "address": "45.XXX.XXX.XXX",
    "lobbyVanishType": "ALL",
    "rank": "DIRECTOR"
}
```

Modelo en la app:

```js
import {model, Schema} from "mongoose";

const PlayersSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: Object
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    uuid: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    options: {
        type: Object
    },
    properties: {
        type: Object
    },
    punishments: {
        type: Object
    },
    countdowns: {
        type: Object
    },
    rewards: {
        type: Array
    },
    friends: {
        type: Array
    },
    dateCreate: {
        type: String
    },
    gameModeId: {
        type: String
    },
    lyCoins: {
        type: Object
    },
    level: {
        type: Object
    },
    clan: {
        type: Object
    },
    lastLocation: {
        type: Object
    },
    address: {
        type: String
    },
    lobbyVanishType: {
        type: String
    },
    rank: {
        type: String
    },
});
export default model("Players", PlayersSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes construir tu objeto de la siguiente

```js
const PlayersSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
  uuid: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  options: {
    "spawn_tp": Boolean,
    "announcements_normal": Boolean,
    "join_message": Boolean,
    "private_msg": Boolean,
    "announcements_streams": Boolean
},,
  properties: {},
  punishments: {},
  countdowns: {},
  rewards: []
  friends: [],
  dateCreate: String,
  gameModeId: String,
  lyCoins: {},
  level: {},
  clan: {},
  lastLocation: {},
  address: String,
  lobbyVanishType: String,
  rank: String,
});
```

Los objetos pueden estar directo en el mismo schema.